# Regex in a properties file

Tags: java, properties

I have a class, where I am comparing two arrays and I need to apply a pattern on the result, such that it leaves out dates. I did some research on regexes and properties files and came up with

```
public class writeconfig {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Properties property = new Properties();
    String datepattern = "(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0?[1-9]|1[012])/((19|20)\\d\\d)";
     Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(datepattern);
     property.setProperty("pattern_use", pattern);

}
```

}

now, it turns out that the set property function, only allows quoted input and I cannot store a pattern in it. Is there some way of doing it? help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: why do you need to store a pattern in a property file ?
you can save the datepattern there

Comment: @udy I need to. So that I can add more features that need to modified in the comparing method, in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Properties` extends `Hashtable`, so you can use the `put(key, value)` and `get(key)` methods to store objects in a `Properties` class.

```
property.put("pattern_use", pattern);
pattern = (Pattern)property.get("pattern_use");
```

Do be aware that you won't be able to store the `Properties` object to a file or anything if you do this because it will try to cast the Pattern to a String. If you need this, I'd just store the regular expression in a properties file and create the Pattern from that. That can be done like this:

```
property.setProperty("pattern_use", pattern.toString());
pattern = Pattern.compile(property.getProperty("pattern_use"));
```

Comment: Thanks. I have stored the pattern in a property file, by using property.put("pattern_use", ""+pattern). I need to retrieve the pattern, in the class where I am loading the properties file. I have loaded the file, with an input stream. But how do I retrieve the pattern and apply it, on an array?

Comment: By doing `""+pattern` all you're doing is converting it to a string. If that's all you really want, to store the pattern use this `property.setProperty("pattern_use", pattern.toString())` and to load the pattern do this `Pattern.compile(properties.getProperty("pattern_use"))`

Comment: Thanks again. Can I also get it as a String using         String prop = property.getProperty("pattern_use"); ?

Comment: Yes. That will return just the regular expression itself.